# Time taken to cash out Stock Investments inside Chase internet banking

Tags: stocks, liquidity

I invested some money (10k) in the stock market.
Chase had introduced a new free feature called
INVESTMENTS by JP Morgan . I like the fact that
internet banking was showing my stock value
right next to the usual checking and savings account.

January / February is a slow month and cash flow is tight. I'm thinking of cashing out the stocks. How long will it takes for money in stocks to become cash in the Chase checking account?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask Chase. There are SEC rules for transaction settlement but there may be additional rules within Chase for transferring those funds between your brokerage account and bank account. With my broker it takes about 3-4 days in total, but I do not bank with them, so it may be faster if you bank with the broker as well.

Also, make sure you are prepared for any tax consequences. If you are selling them for a loss, if you buy them back after cash flow is less "tight", you may be subject to a wash sale rule. If you are selling them for a significant gain, depending on how long you've owned the shares you will be subject to either short-term (less than 1 year) or long-term capital gains taxes.

Answer (score 0):

Under the SEC's T+2 rule, most securities transactions  settle in two business days.